# metal slide binders

Tags: vintage, slides

I recently purchased a box of glass slides and metal binders, also in the box were some very thin frames that when folded were the size of the the metal binder. I am trying to date them and determine how these were used back in the day.
thanks so much for your help

Comment: Some photo(s) may help

Comment: Impossible to help without photos.